# What does "$-k$-times" mean here

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm working through the Ring Theory section of Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra and have come across this question:
[image]

What's getting me is in the mapping, where they write $-1-1-\cdots-1$ ($-k$-times)... What does $-k$-times mean? Is it meant to imply the sequence of subtractions ends up positive? I'm not even sure if that makes any sense. If anyone could explain what it's supposed to mean I'd be grateful.

Comment: If $k<0$ then $-k$ is positive.

Comment: Ah yes of course, mb.

Comment: It's correct as written but would be less confusing with "$|k|$ times".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The homomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{Z} \to R$ is usually written as $n \mapsto n \cdot 1$, so we need to define $n \cdot 1$.

If $n \geq 0$, then
$$n \cdot 1 := \underbrace{1 + \cdots + 1}_{\large n \text{ summands}}.$$
For example, $5 \cdot 1 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1$, etc.

If $n \leq 0$, then $-n \geq 0$. Hence we already know what $ (-n) \cdot 1$ is. We then define*
$$n \cdot 1 := -((-n) \cdot 1).$$
This is exactly
$$\underbrace{(-1) + \cdots + (-1)}_{\large -n \text{ summands}}$$

For example, $(-5) \cdot 1 = (-1) + (-1) + (-1) + (-1) + (-1)$. This has $-(-5)=5$ summands.

*Notice that we *have to* do this since we expect $\varphi(n)=-\varphi(-n)$ for any homomorphism $\varphi$.